# Meaning of the custom http headers in burpsuite academy

Tags: burp-suite, web

I am going through the Burpsuite Academy Training on Serverside security and I came across a section I am not able to grasp fully:

```
Some application frameworks support various non-standard HTTP headers that can be used to override the URL in the original request, such as X-Original-URL and X-Rewrite-URL. If a web site uses rigorous front-end controls to restrict access based on URL, but the application allows the URL to be overridden via a request header, then it might be possible to bypass the access controls using a request like the following:

POST / HTTP/1.1
  X-Original-URL: /admin/deleteUser
```

In the following lab you could modify the HTTP request so that you can access a restricted /admin page by changing the header to set the GET request to "/" and then adding X-Original-URL: /admin as a new line.

I looked up custom http headers online but I am still not able to understand what is really going on ; are these vuls always exploitable or in what cases can this be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is really going on

Some web server infrastructure will either add or re-write URLs and/or headers at various steps. For example, this is common when routing a request through a reverse proxy (e.g. Cloudflare); the proxy will add a header telling the server what IP address the request originally came from. Some server infrastructure will also re-write URLs, for example if there are multiple application servers behind a single request router or application load balancer; in those cases, the "middleware" might add a header (such as `X-Original-URL`) to the request to tell the back-end server what the requested path was before rewriting.

> are these vuls always exploitable

Not at all. First of all, lots of servers either aren't behind any such middleware, or are but don't care; those ones won't even look for such headers, and thus are unaffected by them. Additionally, the middleware itself might modify or filter out any such headers it sees, to avoid a malicious request misleading the back-end server (e.g. avoid the risk of a server thinking a request originated within a local network when it did not). Finally, even with such request modifying going on, and the middleware not handling existing headers well but the backend trusting the middleware, there isn't necessarily any *severe* vulnerability.

For example, suppose there is an admin interface, which you shouldn't be able to reach. The middleware is only supposed to route requests to the admin server from trusted locations, but you fool it by adding the `X-Original-URL` header (whereas if you'd requested a path starting `/admin` directly, the middleware would have rejected your request as unauthorized). *However*, if the admin interface still requires authentication by an authorized admin, you won't be able to do much! It opens up new attack surface (maybe there's a vulnerability in the admin login page?) and lets you determine the path to the hidden admin interface by guessing, but it doesn't actually let you take administrative actions (without finding another vulnerability).

> in what cases can this be used

Generally, you need three things:

- Some form of middleware that is expected to re-write requests (e.g. changing their URLs and adding an `X-Original-URL` header or similar, adding an `X-Original-IP` header, etc.).
- The back-end server needs to check the middleware-added header, but for some reason process the attacker-added value rather than the middleware-added value. This can happen either due to a bug in the middleware not handling existing headers well, or a bug in the backend server not processing the added headers correctly (e.g. maybe there are multiple space-delimited values in the header, to account for multiple layers of rewriting, and the middleware adds the latest value at one end but the client trusts the value at the other end, the attacker-added one). In rare cases you might get a server that checks for middleware-added headers without actually being behind any such middleware, which also can be vulnerable (skip the first check).
- The backend server (or, potentially, some middleware layer) needs to make a security decision based on the (incorrect or incorrectly-parsed) contents of that header. Typically this takes the form of allowing access to data or privileged actions that would normally be disallowed, but it could also be things like concealment from intrusion detection systems or spoofing log entries.

Note that, in all cases, the headers' names and value formats might be different. This is an attack that depends entirely on the victim (their infrastructure, the way their server interacts with it). The header names and formats are not at all standardized; a developer needs to look up what to expect from their middleware and code to that expectation. With that said, in some cases a server framework (such as a web application framework) might come built-in with support for some of the more common headers. For example, Cloudflare's reverse proxies forward the client IP address in an appended header called [`CF-Connecting-IP`, and might also add or update headers such as `True-Client-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For`](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/reference/http-request-headers/).

However, in many cases it's developer-configured. See for example the answer to [this question about configuring nginx to forward the real client IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/837915/forwarding-real-remote-ip-to-proxied-server-with-nginx), where the developer used `X-Real-IP` but could as easily have used, say, `X-Client-Address` or whatever. Similarly, the actual backend server (Apache, in that case) received configuration to recognize the added header and its meaning. Bear in mind that the header isn't visible to you (an outside client) - it's added to your requests once they hit the network-facing middleware server, well after leaving your machine - so in some cases figuring out what headers are expected is a lot of guesswork.

Comment: All right thanks a lot! really helped me , just one more question , do all servers recognize this formatting of custom headers or is that also relative?

Comment: Take a look at the last two paragraphs, where I added an explanation about this.